# What is the eloquent query to get users who has a field value and this value is part of given array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have users records like that

| **id** | **fields** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["fashion","commercial"] |
| 2 | ["commercial"] |

and I want to get the users how has at least one field form  that array **["fashion", "food", "sport"]**

Comment: Are you running a database dialect that has a dedicated function to parse json fields?

Answer (score 0):

Although you could use whereIn() like:

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->whereIn('fields', ["fashion", "food", "sport"])
             ->get();
```

I don't think that it would return anything because of your "fields" column structure. Probably the easiest way is to get all the users and filter them using `array_intersect()`, it would look something like this:

```
foreach($users as $user){
    if (array_intersect($user, $fields)) {
        $filteredUser[] = $user;
    }
}
```